# How to speed up getServerSideProps with next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, server-side-rendering

When I'm using getServerSideProps with next js and it almost takes 5 or 6 seconds for the page to load . I tried using only one url to fetch and not many but again it takes alot for the page to load .

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
   let data ;
   try {
      data = axios.get("url")
   } catch(e){
      data = "error"
   }
   return {
     data: data,
   };
 };
```

I was wondering is there any trick to speed up getServerSideProps data fetching so I could have faster initial page load ?

Comment: Have you tried testing the API call in isolation/independently of your frontend and seeing what response time is like? Are you confident it's not the API specifically that is slow

Answer (score 1):

got this solution while searching for this bug

```
const isServerReq = req => !req.url.startsWith('/_next');

function Post({ post }) {
  // Render post...
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const initData = isServerReq(req) ? await fetch(...) : null;

  return {
    props: {
      initData,
    },
  }
}
```

issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/13910